# How can I farm for P Flonzor parts?

Tags: disgaea-4

I'm trying to get the P Flonzor ship parts to get to the Land of Carnage but after interogating enemies I get junk in the treasure chests and have to start all over. I know [which monsters I need to get them from](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995078-disgaea-4-a-promise-unforgotten/60311106) but that guide doesn't explain very much beyond that.

What's the most efficient way to farm for these? Should I interrogate a whole bunch of monsters all at once and check treasures one by one, or should I interrogate one monster and repeatedly check the same chest, resetting if I don't get it?

Do some areas have a higher likelyhood of having P Flonzor parts in treasure? I heard X Dimension chests have a *lower* chance of being Flonzor parts.

Comment: I might add that this is one of the most annoying parts of any disgaea game ever. WTF.

Comment: Really? I've found that P Flonzor Parts have better chances of appearing on X-Dimension maps than the normal map...

Comment: @Krazer that's why I was confused by the advice, I haven't found one yet to confirm though. I was hoping for better advice before I resumed looking since this sounds like a looong one.

Comment: Have you tried saving before you "interrogate" units? I found it helpful to save before I "interrogate" them and then reload if I don't get what you are looking for (it takes a while to do though). I had the hardest time with the Meowkin Pirates for the Body part. Dx

Comment: Did you get your P-Flonzor parts or is there any information that I can contribute to my answer to help you do so?

Comment: @skovacs1 honestly I've been so demotivated I just haven't been going for them (or playing D4). It's a great answer though

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to interrogate a single monster over and over again and reset, though for the sake of the collect all ship parts trophy you should keep any other ship parts collected in their place and go to capture an additional monster.

From my experience in the game, the X-Dimension chests were slightly more likely to have them or other high level ship parts, but they are also far more difficult to collect the part from. If you get a different Flonzor series part, you're on the right track and you just need to keep iterating.

You should absolutely save before interrogating, as reloading a save from after interrogating seems to have no effect on the item in the chest.

Finding the individual P Flonzor parts was actually not nearly as much of a challenge as getting the final body piece. It only took me about 4-5 hours of work to get all of them once I had unlocked all of the x-dimension levels.

Comment: The third paragraph is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This information was taken from [this guide to obtaining all ship parts](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/disgaea-4/128071-guide-obtaining-all-ship-parts-fun-slayer-weapons.html). You should know that collecting these parts is best done during the late late game because you'll want to be quite powerful and you'll need a highly ranked item to do this easily.

### Getting ship parts

Getting any ship parts is relatively straightforward and follows the same process for all enemies except pirates.

1. **Ship parts have the highest chance of appearing on X-dimension maps and exceedingly little chance anywhere else.** Those maps are a pain so if you can do this without any of the story maps done (by travelling back in time) except for X-True Final Weapons (8-8), your life will be so much easier because it guarantees chests will ONLY spawn on a very easy X-dimension map as chests don't spawn on uncompleted maps.

> Note: To unlock the X-dimension, all you need to do is buy the Promotionhell Tickets from the Scalper(Cu Sith) in a mystery gate, selling you the first half on floors 1-49 and the second half on floors 51-99, but note that they are quite expensive - A strategy to find him is to run 10 floors looking and reload if he is not found and another is to force mystery gates to appear by Gency-ing out of the X7th floor of any item; save; Re-enter and reach the X0th floor without encountering a mystery gate; exit and save; X1 on the next set of floors will have a guaranteed mystery gate.

2. **Go to the item world of a highly ranked item (like a Legendary R39) and start capturing enemies. The higher the level the enemies the better as lower level enemies don't give ship parts.**
3. **You can capture up to 16 enemies at a time.** After that, leave via Mr. Gency or by clearing a X0 floor. You must be able to create the class and tier of enemy that you are trying to capture (and you should note that you can't create androids of any tier until you've gone back in time). The enemy has to be lower level than Valvatorez, meaning that Valvatorez should be as high a level as possible. You must have the Discipline Room Evil Symbol unlocked.
4. **SAVE.**
5. **Discipline the enemies until the *Find Treasure* option becomes available and choose it to spawn a chest on X-True Final Weapon. Go there and destroy the chest. If you don't get a ship part, quit and reload your last save. If you do get a ship part, continue from step 4 until all enemies have been Disciplined.**

Different varieties of enemies give out different ship parts. Prinnies and pirates take much longer and may require completing a different story map, thus complicating the process.

**Prinnies** - They don't spawn in the item world so you need to go to an X-Dimension map. 7-6 is easy, but it can spawn chests in unreachable places. If the Prinny doesn't spawn a chest on 8-8, you're better off reloading than wasting your time. Because these involve finishing another map, it's best to save these for last.

**Pirates** - They suck for this because they appear randomly. The best way to hunt these is to get an item to floor 90, making sure it's on the right boost path. Duplicate the item and repeatedly run the last 10 floors until you find the pirate you're looking for. Return to base and save once you find one. Go find the next crew and if you didn't find them, reload and try again. Pirates arrive at specific turns and they never appear on a floor with a mystery gate. This is very tedious so you may want to break up the monotony by running the story maps. The list of pirates with more information can be found [here](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Pirates#Disgaea_4)

### Targeting specific parts (P-Flonzor X in this case)

Remember how different varieties of enemies give out different ship parts, well there's [a list of which enemies drop which parts](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Pirate_Editor).

For P-Flonzor X, the list reads (sorted by difficulty to get the part):

> - **Head** - Capture **Professor**.
> - **Wings** - Capture **Magic Knight**.
> - **Legs** - Capture **Rifle Dragon**.
> - **L Arm** - Capture **Death**.
> - **R Arm** - Capture **Prinny**.
> - **Body** - Defeat **Meowkin Pirates** inside the item world. Floor 91+(Higher chance in treasure route).

Lucky you, the page also includes information on what levels all of these enemies spawn on:

> - Professor Tier 5 - Map X10-1
> - Magic Knight Tier 5 - Map X10-1
> - Rifle Dragon Tier 2 - Map 9-6
> - Death Tier 6 - Map X10-7
> - Prinny Tier 5 - Map 7-6
> - Meowkin Pirates - Item World Floor 91+(Higher chance in treasure route)